# How can I convert a Greasemonkey script into a restartless Firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

I need to convert a Greasemonkey script into a restartless Firefox addon.

It used to be possible to do this very easily using the Scriptify extension, but the extension has not been kept up to date with the latest changes to the Firefox browser, and no longer works.

Is there an alternate way to accomplish this?

Comment: There's no one/easy way, because there is almost no legitimate need to do this.  But go ahead and make a tool and/or a framework if you think there *is* a strong need.   Also, porting a GM script is fairly trivial ***if*** the script doesn't use any of the `GM_` API.

Comment: If there wasnt a legitimate need for this, i wouldnt have asked.
I don't have the knowledge to make a tool or framework, and as there already is/was a tool, it would seem pretty pointless to re-invent the wheel. The documentation on restartless add-ons seems pretty poor, perhaps thats why nobody has done it.

Comment: Well, if you can show us that there is a legitimate need, someone might be motivated to work on it.  I've written many hundreds of scripts and a handful of add-ons. **I've** yet to see a need. ... Yes, the documentation (and support) for add-ons is poor. Yet, there are tens of thousands of working add-ons!  The need for a converter is miniscule -- hence there is no working converter.

Comment: The legitimate need seems quite obvious to me, and the question pretty much already spells it out which is why i didnt feel it needed to be mentioned.

Its obviously easier to install a restartless addon, than an add-on that needs the browser to be restarted. And if a gm script writer wants to convert their script into a restartless addon, there is no easy way to do it. Its again easier to install a restartless addon, than having to install the greasemonkey extension and then install a greasemonkey script on top of that.

Comment: You install the GM add-on once, and after that, installing scripts is dirt-simple. More importantly, uninstalling, creating, and maintaining scripts is vastly faster and easier than any add-on, restartless or no.  If you can do it in a script; it's counter-productive to make it an add-on.     Add-ons should only be for things that scripts can't do. ... As for the question, the only thing *obvious* is that it needs work -- hence the low views, zero upvotes, and zero answers.  Make a proper case and/or provide specifics and what you've attempted.

Comment: yes but the fact you need to install the gm extension first is an extra step thats not necessary, a gm script compiler that could convert scripts to restartless addons, would mean the maintenance of the script would not be a problem, its just the same as maintaining a gm script, as the compiler will convert it to an addon in seconds.

the sort of people that would use this addon, would not be technically knowledgeable like us programmers, which is why the more simple the installation process for them, the better, and less user support issues and problems for them and me

Comment: Vindicated.. the author of the original add-on, scriptify has updated his extension, so it works again with the newer firefoxen.

So Brock Adams, are you trying to tell me the highly ranked Firefox developer behind the Scriptify extension, is just wasting his time by writing and maintaing the Scriptify extension? I don't understand why you had to make such a big deal out of this, just because you could not see a need for it, does not mean there isnt a need for it, and you shouldnt try and speak for all developers either, try being a bit more humble

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out, the developer of the Scriptify extension has updated his extension for compatibility with the newer Firefox browsers. Hooray! :)

**UPDATE** Now that Firefox has implemented the WebExtensions API for Firefox Extensions, it means its very easy to create restartless Firefox extensions from Greasemonkey scripts, as Firefox extensions built with the "Web Extensions" API are by default restartless, and you can include the gm script as a content script in the Firefox extension.

For an example of how to create a Firefox Extension using the new WebExtensions API, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension